$\Phi_n(x)$ and $x^m-1$ are coprime in $Z/pZ[x]$ if $(p, n) = 1$
So I'm studying the proof of a weak version of Dirichlet's theorem.
On one step from my notes I use this fact:
If $p$ is prime, $(p,n)$ are coprime, $\Phi_n(x)$ is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial, let $m|n$ and $m<n$, then $(\Phi_n(x), x^m-1) = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It's not 100% clear to me why it's true. I get why you need the condition $(n,p)=1$ because for example if $n=p=3$ the statement is false: $\Phi_3(x) = (x-1)^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

@QiaochuYuan why? m | n if m and n are natural numbers implies that m ≤ n

Whoops, sorry about that.

The condition that $\gcd(p, n) = 1$ is equivalent to the condition that $x^n - 1$ is separable, hence it has distinct roots (over a splitting field). Using the cyclotomic factorization
$$x^n - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)$$
it follows that $\Phi_n(x)$ and $x^m - 1$, which both divide $x^n - 1$, consist of products of disjoint factors in the cyclotomic factorization (namely, $x^m - 1 = \prod_{d \mid m} \Phi_d(x)$ and all of these cyclotomic polynomials are different from the $\Phi_n(x)$ factor); this means that the two polynomials don't have any roots in common (over a splitting field), so are relatively prime.
Conceptually the point is that the cyclotomic factorization can be used to show that the roots of $\Phi_n(x)$, over an arbitrary field $K$, are exactly the elements $\alpha \in K^{\times}$ of multiplicative order exactly $n$. Meanwhile the roots of $x^m - 1$ consist of elements of order dividing $m$, none of which can have order $n$.

I see! Thank you.
